# Rails 3.1 Ransack HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, has-and-belongs-to-many, ransack

Is HABTM supported by Ransack?

Having the models:

- Shop HABTM Categories
- Category HABTM Shops

Can I use ransack to search a Shop by a single category?
What does the form look like?

Answer (score 13):

I think the field you're trying to use would be

```
:categories_id_eq
```

Usage would be something like this

```
<%= f.label :categories_id_eq, "Category" %>
<%= f.collection_select :categories_id_eq, Category.order(:title), :id, :title %>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be aware that there are gotchas:
while this workds fine

```
:categories_id_eq
```

If you want to find products in any category you can go with

```
:categories_id_in
```

But if you need to get products belonging to all of categories selected it wont work as expected:

```
:categories_id_all
```

returns zero results see discussions:

[Rails, Ransack: How to search HABTM relationship for "all" matches instead of "any"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409627/rails-ransack-how-to-search-habtm-relationship-for-all-matches-instead-of-a)

[Convert ActiveRecord habtm query to Arel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420773/convert-activerecord-habtm-query-to-arel/13445889#13445889)
.