# Search by empty list for many-to-many relation using ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I searched about how to pass empty array to ransack, for example:

```
@search = PromotionsRetailer.search(retailer_id_in: [])
```

This sql statement:

```
"SELECT `promotions_retailers`.* FROM `promotions_retailers` "
```

I found this [link](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/212), to add -1 to empty array, so i used `search(retailer_id_in: ([] + [-1]))`.

1. Any solution is better than this solution?
2. How to search using `retailer_id` in promotion table, if i have many-to-many relation between promotions/retailers without using breaking table `PromotionsRetailer` by [ransack gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack)?

Answer (score 0):

First part of question is vital. This should be a separate question.

Unfortunately, there in no more elegant way to cope with it, than:

```
search(retailer_id_in: ([] + [-1]))
```

The problem lays somewhere in the gem. And if you pass empty array, or array filled with `nil` values as a parameter, there will be join in SQL, but all the conditions will be ignored, e.g.:

Ruby:

```
Article.ransack({authors_id_in: [nil, nil, nil]}).result
```

SQL:

```
SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "articles_authors" ON "articles_authors"."article_id" = "articles"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "authors" ON "authors"."id" = "articles_authors"."author_id"
```

---

Your second part of question is about searching through HABTM relations using ransack, which is explained in [Rails 3.1 Ransack HABTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619246/rails-3-1-ransack-habtm) pretty good.

Therefore:

```
Promotion.ransack({retailer_id_in: [1,2,3]}).result
```

You should not use `PromotionsRetailer` class itself.